# Performance issue with Doctrine ORM Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox with really large collection

Tags: php, performance, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a ManyToMany relationship to an Entity (Fair <-> Hotels) with over 12.000 entries. When I'm using the DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox in my form, the application runs out of memory. It seems like the ObjectMultiCheckbox loads every single entity which is saved in the database even though the Fair entity isn't assigned to any Hotel (and vice versa).

Here is the Fair entity with the Hotel relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Hotel", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fair_core_has_hotel", joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fair_core_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
 */  
private $hotel;
```

And here is  the ObjectMultiCheckbox in the FairForm:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'hotel',
    'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
    'options' => array(
        'entity' => 'hotel',
        'unchecked_value' => '',
        'object_manager' => $em,
        'target_class' => 'Customer\Entity\Hotel',
        'label_generator' => function($targetEntity) {
            return "".$targetEntity->getLabel();
        },
        'attributes' => array('required' => false),
    ),
));
```

Already tried to change the fetch-mode to EXTRA_LAZY but it doesn't make any difference. Also the relation is unidirectional, the Hotel entity doesn't know anything about the Fair entity.

Is there any solution? Or have I done something wrong?

Here are the modules I'm currently using:
[image]

Comment: How many hotel records do you have? Is your relationship between fair and hotel uni-directional? If not please also show the other side.

Comment: I have about 12.000 hotel records. The relationship is uni-directional. The Doctrine Proxy (DoctrineModule\Form\Element\Proxy) loads every entry in the loadObjects()-method, thats why it crashes. Maybe I can try it with defining an own find_method in the options.

Comment: So correct me if I am understanding you wrong, but you want to make a multi-select list with 12.000 hotels to choose from?

Comment: no, only the assigned hotels are shown in the list. You can assign other hotels to a fair with a search function.

Comment: in the setValue()-method of the form element, only the assigned hotels are loaded, so this basically works as expected, but for some reason, doctrine loads every single hotel record in the background which are stored in the $valueOptions variable, which is a simple array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the working of the doctrine `ObjectMultiCheckbox` form element.
In [the Doctrine2 form element documentation](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md) you can read that:

> When the Form gets rendered the `findAll` method of the `ObjectRepository` will be executed by default.

In your case it means it will find all entities of target class `'Customer\Entity\Hotel'` so this means all 12.000 records.

No wonder there are some issues with memory :)

I think you will have to refactor this part of the code so it will only work with a selection of hotels.

You can read on how to do this in [**Example 3: extended version**](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md#example-3--extended-version). There they show an example where they configure a `find_method` that uses a specific method from your repository where you can limit the result.

Comment: you are absolutely right, thats the default behaviour, what I didn't realised. I can define my own findBy-method to limit the search results. Thanks for pointing that out.